# Jquery validation for each field

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I am using jquery-validate.I dont need validation for the whole form but for individual feilds since I hide few fields initially...

I tried using `$("#form").validate().element(#field_id);`

The above does not seem to work.
Kindly show me an correct example to validate each field in the form

I need validation on each field since I am hiding few fields initially and showing them later on button click.

Answer (score 0):

This link may help you.
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid

To validate entire form use

$('#formid').valid();

Answer (score 0):

> I dont need validation for the whole form but for individual feilds since I hide few fields initially...

If your problem is validating hidden fields, I would recommend checking out the `ignore` option rather than attempting to validate a subset of the elements in the form:

```
$("#myForm").validate({
    ignore: ":hidden"
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/TEGJM/

If you *do* need to validate individual elements, you need to quote your selector:

```
$("#form").validate().element("#field_id");
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/cDjQR/

Comment: I have tried using this but what is happening is when I click on the submit button it is validating as well as sending the form data to servlet

Comment: @newbie: Does the example I posted have that problem?